# URL in popup JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

i have following scenario
first i need to send request to back end,that will return a URL..i need to open the URL in the 
popup.. i am confused for this

i have tried opening popup both using the prime-faces and web flow but i don't have clearly how to open popup using new url each time

we are using JSF, prime faces and spring webflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript's [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) function.

E.g.

```xml
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
        <f:ajax render="popup" />
    </h:commandButton>

    <h:panelGroup id="popup">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty bean.url}">
            <script>window.open('#{bean.url}');</script>
        </ui:fragment>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

with

```
private String url;

public void submit() {
    this.url = sendRequestToServiceAndRetrieveURL();
}

// ...
```

Comment: thanks.. should i call  getURL function from command button independently

Comment: Uh, no. Just let the command button set the retrieved URL as a `url` property and then return or ajax-update the page. I updated the answer.

Comment: i am facing tow more problem..one is i want to call an action when i close this popup secondly i need to change width and height of this popup..can u help me to do that

Comment: That are different questions. Press `Ask Question` button on right top to post them.

Comment: hmm here is [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243611/calling-action-from-the-popup)

Comment: will the popup open in IE7.because i am not able to open there