# Calling action from the popup

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I am facing when i am opening a popup.

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:ajax render="popup" />
</h:commandButton>

<h:panelGroup id="popup">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty bean.url}">
        <script>window.open('#{bean.url}');</script>
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

i want to call an action when i close this popup

secondly i need to change width and height of this popup.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to call an action when i close this popup

Give a `close` button perform the desire action and redirect user to a page which is meant to closed on load by javascript

> secondly i need to change width and height of this popup.

You can specify `height` & `width` in [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: any code will be appreciated..i dont have much knowledge of java script

Comment: have you seen the link given ?

Comment: something should be blocking it

Answer (score 0):

> *i want to call an action when i close this popup*

That's only possible if the enduser submits a `<h:form>` from inside the popup. You **cannot** hook a bean action when the enduser presses X button or Ctrl+W or Alt+F4. There's the `window.onbeforeunload` hook, but this does not allow you for reliably sending a HTTP request to the server side, which is necessary to invoke a bean action.

---

> *secondly i need to change width and height of this popup.*

You can do that by supplying extra arguments to [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open). See also the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open):

```
window.open('#{bean.url}', 'yourwindowname', 'width=600,height=480');
```

Comment: above code is not opening popup in IE7.can we have a way around

Comment: Then your IE7 has a popup blocker installed. Disable it or use a HTML/JS/CSS div-with-overlay approach or use a 3rd party component library like PrimeFaces/RichFaces which have components for this.

Comment: i am already using primefaces..but i dont know how to correctly do that..my popup blocked is disabled

Comment: The block issue is a different problem than you originally asked about. You've apparently posted a different question (which is fine) please continue there.

Answer (score 0):

> *we are using onbeforeunload hook for calling the function from the popup when we popup  window*

```
<script>
        window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
            document.forms["showpdf"].elements["hiddenBtn"].click();
            }
    </script>
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
            <h:form id="showpdf">
                <iframe src="#{docProd.url}" width="100%" height="100%">     </iframe>
                <div align="center"><p:commandButton id="hiddenBtn"
                    onclick="#{docProd.resetUrl}" style="display:none"   /></div>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
    </ui:composition>
```