# Window.open not working with IE7

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf

I am facing when i am opening a popup with IE 7..is there any way around for this

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
<f:ajax render="popup" />
</h:commandButton>

<h:panelGroup id="popup">
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty bean.url}">
    <script>window.open('#{bean.url}');</script>
</ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then your IE7 is configured to block (certain) popups or has a popup blocker installed. Often it will block popups which points to external sites. Reconfigure IE or disable the blocker.

An alternative is to use a HTML/JS/CSS div-with-overlay approach or a 3rd party JSF component library like PrimeFaces/RichFaces which have components for this. For example, PrimeFaces with [`<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf).

Comment: The `<p:dialog>` part in my answer is blue and clickable. It links to the demo page on PrimeFaces. It contains a bunch of examples. Play around with them.

Comment: i have gone through this earlier... mine only problem is that i want to check condition that popup will be affected by [response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203665/url-in-popup-jsf) coming from server..dont know how that condition wil be solved here :(

Comment: any solution for this problem.actualy this is very critical..:(

Comment: Oh, it points to an external URL? You cannot use overlay for this without proxying its content (which is not a simple task).